# Add the spider's name to each line of log

Tags: python, web-scraping, logging, scrapy, web-crawler

I am looking for a way to prefix each log produced by Scrapy with the name of the spider that generated it. Until now, I was launching each spider synchronously in a loop, so it was easy to track which spider generated which log. But I have recently refactored my code in order to either accept a list of spiders as argument, or launch them all at once throught the `CrawlerProcess()` function. The result is that they are launched asynchronously, so the logs are all mixed up.

I have thought about adding something like `[%(name)]` to the LOG_FORMAT setting, but the name produced is the module that called it (scrapy.core.engine, scrapy.utils.log, etc.) and not the spider's name.

I also tried creating an extension that would modify the crawler's settings by retrieving `spider.name` and adding it to the LOG_FORMAT constant, but as far as I'm aware changing the settings while the crawler is running has no effect (and I haven't found a clean way of doing it since they are immutable).

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Thank you

- I tried setting a custom LOG_FORMAT but there does not seem to be any way to access the spider's name ;
- I tried using an `extension` to catch the crawler's settings and modify them, but they are immutable and they are only evaluated at the beginning of the process ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a [custom log format](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#custom-log-formats), and set it as the [log formatter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-formatter) for the project.

Basically you need to extend Scrapy's [log formatter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/logformatter.html#LogFormatter) and set the message with the new format.

- Example with [crawled](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#scrapy.logformatter.LogFormatter.crawled) and [scraped](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#scrapy.logformatter.LogFormatter.scraped):

main2.py:

```py
from scrapy import logformatter
import logging
import os
from twisted.python.failure import Failure
from scrapy.utils.request import referer_str

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


SCRAPEDMSG = "Scraped from %(src)s" + os.linesep + "%(item)s"
# DROPPEDMSG = "Dropped: %(exception)s" + os.linesep + "%(item)s"
CRAWLEDMSG = "Crawled (%(status)s) %(request)s%(request_flags)s (referer: %(referer)s)%(response_flags)s"
# ITEMERRORMSG = "Error processing %(item)s"
# SPIDERERRORMSG = "Spider error processing %(request)s (referer: %(referer)s)"
# DOWNLOADERRORMSG_SHORT = "Error downloading %(request)s"
# DOWNLOADERRORMSG_LONG = "Error downloading %(request)s: %(errmsg)s"


class ExampleLogFormatter(logformatter.LogFormatter):
    def crawled(self, request, response, spider):
        request_flags = f' {str(request.flags)}' if request.flags else ''
        response_flags = f' {str(response.flags)}' if response.flags else ''
        return {
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'msg': f'{spider.name} {CRAWLEDMSG}',
            'args': {
                'status': response.status,
                'request': request,
                'request_flags': request_flags,
                'referer': referer_str(request),
                'response_flags': response_flags,
                # backward compatibility with Scrapy logformatter below 1.4 version
                'flags': response_flags
            }
        }

    def scraped(self, item, response, spider):
        if isinstance(response, Failure):
            src = response.getErrorMessage()
        else:
            src = response
        return {
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'msg': f'{spider.name} {SCRAPEDMSG}',
            'args': {
                'src': src,
                'item': item,
            }
        }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spider = 'example_spider'
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    settings['LOG_FORMATTER'] = 'tempbuffer.main2.ExampleLogFormatter'
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(spider)
    process.start()
```

spider.py:

```py
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['scrapingclub.com']
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//h3/text()').get()
        item['price'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="card-body"]/h4/text()').get()
        yield item
```

Output:

```py
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: example_spider Crawled (200) <GET https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/> (referer: None)
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: example_spider Scraped from <200 https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/>
{'title': 'Long-sleeved Jersey Top', 'price': '$12.99'}
```

**Update:**

A non global working solution:

```py
import logging
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['scrapingclub.com']
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/']

    configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=name + ': %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

    def parse(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//h3/text()').get()
        item['price'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="card-body"]/h4/text()').get()
        yield item
```

**Update 2:** Finally a working solution.

main2.py:

```py
import logging
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


# create a logging filter
class ContentFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.spider_name = ''
        # enter the spider's name
        if hasattr(record, 'spider'):
            record.spider_name = record.spider.name

        return True

        # record.spider.name was enough for my tests, but maybe you'll need this:
        # record.spider_name = ''
        # if hasattr(record, 'crawler'):
        #     record.spider_name = record.crawler.spidercls.name
        # elif hasattr(record, 'spider'):
        #     record.spider_name = record.spider.name
        # return True


# Extend scrapy.Spider class
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # the new format with "spider_name" variable:
        formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(spider_name)s]: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

        # add the new format and filter to all the handlers
        for handler in logging.root.handlers:
            handler.formatter = formatter
            handler.addFilter(ContentFilter())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spider1 = 'example_spider'
    spider2 = 'example_spider2'
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'

    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(spider1)
    process.crawl(spider2)
    process.start()
```

spider.py:

```py
from tempbuffer.main2 import Spider


# use the extended "Spider" class
class ExampleSpider(Spider):
    name = 'example_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['scrapingclub.com']
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['price'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="card-body"]/h4/text()').get()
        yield item


# use the extended "Spider" class
class ExampleSpider2(Spider):
    name = 'example_spider2'
    allowed_domains = ['scrapingclub.com']
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//h3/text()').get()
        yield item
```

Comment: I considered doing that but that would require overwriting every function in the original Formatter. Do you know if there is a way to do just that, but using a single function that targets all possible states ? (dropped, crawler, scraped, etc.)

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, but some modules are not affected by this, such as `scrapy.utils.signal` and `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect`. I think it's because these modules are not part of the crawler, but the engine and middleware.
I have an idea to create an extension, access each module's logger and change the format by prefixing `spider.name` to each of them. However, I don't know if this is possible. Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: @Yoyoda  your theory is likely possible, but writing such a custom extension would likely take a significant amount of time and research and debugging to implement.  I think it might be a bit beyond the scope of what you can find on stackoverflow.  If you have already tried implementing this yourself then I would encourage you to post your attempt so that users can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I have not yet tried to implement it. This feels like an overly complicated solution to what seems like a simple need. I might open an issue on Scrapy's GitHub because I feel like everyone would benefit from having their spider's names in their logs. It would greatly help for monitoring logs when the spiders are asynchronous.

Comment: @Yoyoda I'll try to find a solution for this. In the meantime see the update, is this kind of output you're looking for?

Comment: @Yoyoda please see `update 2`, it works =)

Comment: @SuperUser I know I'm asking a lot but isn't there a way to obviate having to write code in each spider separately ? I have like 200 spiders and can't really add code to all of them, which is the main reason I was trying to use log formatters, extensions, etc. I thank you however, because I think your second update works and I'll still try to implement it if I can't find a less time intensive way. Thanks !

Comment: I've implemented it in an extension using the spider_opened method and I think it works. I'll update you guys when I'm sure it does.

Comment: I've been using the new logger for 2 days and I have a couple observations. The filter does not work on spiders that use the scrapy-playwright library since their log records do not have a `spider.name`. To counteract this I've tried simply adding spider.name to every formatter of the root handlers, without using a filter. It works only for the first spider launched, but since the root logger has been modified, every spider after that emits logs with the name of that first spider.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SuperUser I managed to do what I needed without having to add code in each spider individually. Everything happens inside of an extension, more specifically inside the `spider_opened` method. Here is the code :

```
class CustomLogExtension:

    class ContentFilter(logging.Filter):
        """
        Creates a filter that will
        """
        def filter(self, record):
            record.spider_name = ''
            # enter the spider's name
            if hasattr(record, 'spider'):
                record.spider_name = record.spider.name

            return True

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        # first check if the extension should be enabled and raise NotConfigured otherwise
        if not crawler.settings.getbool('CUSTOM_LOG_EXTENSION'):
            raise NotConfigured

        # instantiate the extension object
        ext = cls()

        # connect the extension object to signals
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)

        # return the extension object
        return ext

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        """Prefixes the spider's name to every log emitted."""

        formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(spider_name)s] %(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
        # add the new format and filter to all the handlers
        for handler in logging.root.handlers:
            handler.formatter = formatter
            handler.addFilter(self.ContentFilter())
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer from @SuperUser rather than accepting your own if their answer lead to the correct answer.

Comment: @achille, I just did. Thanks for the suggestion.